# Error Inserting Image in Oracle BLOB with Codeigniter

Tags: image, oracle, codeigniter, blob

I am trying to insert an image into an oracle database using the Codeigniter framework and a BLOB data type. However, everything I try gives me the following two errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: oci_parse(): ORA-00972: identifier is too long
>   Filename: oci8/oci8_driver.php
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: oci_set_prefetch() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   Filename: oci8/oci8_driver.php

This is my database table:

```
CREATE TABLE photos (
   id    int,
   photo blob
);
```

My controller function:

```
function do_upload() {
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

     if ( $this->upload->do_upload() ){
         $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
         $this->upload_model->upload_photo($upload_data['full_path']);
     }
     else {
         echo $this->upload->display_errors();
     }
}
```

My model function:

```
public function upload_photo($full_path) {   
    $fp = fopen($full_path, 'r'); 
    $image  = fread($fp, filesize($full_path)); 
    fclose($fp); 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images ('id', 'photo')
             VALUES ('45', '" . $image . "')";
    $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling Oracle LOBs in PHP is a bit more complex than dealing with simple data types. First you need to create a new  OCI descriptor of certain type, then use it in SQL statement. See this link for details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-new-descriptor.php

Here is simple code example from php.net:

```
<?php
/* This script demonstrates file upload to LOB columns
 * The formfield used for this example looks like this
 * <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 * <input type="file" name="lob_upload" />
 * ...
 */
  if (!isset($lob_upload) || $lob_upload == 'none'){
?>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Upload file: <input type="file" name="lob_upload" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" /> - <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
<?php
  } else {

     // $lob_upload contains the temporary filename of the uploaded file

     // see also the features section on file upload,
     // if you would like to use secure uploads

     $conn = oci_connect($user, $password);
     $lob = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
     $stmt = oci_parse($conn, "insert into $table (id, the_blob)
               values(my_seq.NEXTVAL, EMPTY_BLOB()) returning the_blob into :the_blob");
     oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':the_blob', $lob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
     oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
     if ($lob->savefile($lob_upload)){
        oci_commit($conn);
        echo "Blob successfully uploaded\n";
     }else{
        echo "Couldn't upload Blob\n";
     }
     $lob->free();
     oci_free_statement($stmt);
     oci_close($conn);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

problem in **datatype** use **LONGBLOB** insted of **BLOB**

```
CREATE TABLE photos (
   id    int,
   photo longblob
);
```